# c++ flushing the buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, cout

I know there are many buffer questions on here but I can't seem find a clear answer on this.

```
std::cout << "write to screen" << std::endl;
```

I know this code will write to the screen and flush the buffer because of the "endl", but if I wrote this:

```
std::cout << "write to screen";
```

Wouldn't the buffer be flushed regardless since the text has been outputted to the screen?

Comment: If your second line was equivalent, aside from omitting the explicit flush, the answer might be yes. Put another way, omitting the `\n` can significantly change things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wouldn't the buffer be flushed regardless since the text has been outputted to the screen?

Assuming that you have seen the text outputted to the screen, then **yes**, the buffer has been flushed.

I believe the confusion is regarding this line:

```
std::cout << "write to screen";
```

The absence of `std::endl` **doesn't** mean "don't flush the buffer".  It simply means "I'm not saying when to flush the buffer".

Comment: I'm starting to get the impression that "flushing the buffer" is generally not something that needs to be considered when writing code. It flushes on a successful output and automatically flushes when it reaches a certain "watermark".

Comment: @Memnite it **very often** does not need to be considered.

Comment: @Memnite _"It flushes on a successful output and automatically flushes when it reaches a certain 'watermark'"_ So that's exactly what I've been answering in detail?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yours was a fine answer.  I think there was some guesswork needed regarding what the *real question* was.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to ensure your `std::ostream` is flushed:

1. Manually with [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush), or a direct call to [`ostream::flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush).
2. Depending on a later used input stream being bound to your ostream: [`std::basic_ios::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie).
3. Depending on the tie to C streams: [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

   This means that anything which would flush the corresponding C stream will also flush the C++ stream, like a call to `fflush()`, or the (maybe automatically) selected buffering strategy.
   Like line-buffering.

   From C11 draft:

   > #### 7.21.3 Files
   >
   > 3 When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the
   >   destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and
   >   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*,
   >   characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
   >   a buffer is filled. When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be
   >   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
   >   encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
   >   environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
   >   when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
   >   characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is
   >   implementation-defined, and may be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions.
   >   7 At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly
   >   — *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing
   >   conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output). As initially
   >   opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
   >   output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
   >   to an interactive device.
4. Waiting on the internal buffer overflowing.

Now, as a general guideline: Don't manually flush your streams, doing so can significantly degrade performance. Unless, of course, it's neccessary for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

will write to the screen *before*  executing the next line of code, while

```
std::cout << "Hello\n";
```

will print the same, but some time before your program exits normally or you use `std::cin` (or another instream you tie to `std::cout` by hand). That means that if your program is terminated abruptly or hangs in an infinite loop, you might not see the output at all.

Comment: Not quite right - the buffer is flushed as soon it is full (stdio buffers might be tiny)

Comment: @DieterLücking I think this is covered by "some time before". Even if it does not buffer at all, my statement should still be true.

Comment: Actually, it will have the same flushing semantics as `stdout`, or flush even more often.

Comment: @Deduplicator I never said it will not flush early, just that it might or might not. The only thing we know is that it will flush before one of the above mentioned happen (I did not write *"immediately before"*). I am sorry, I still do not understand why what I wrote is wrong. It would be nice if you could elaborate or just correct my answer if you prefer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

> *"Wouldn't the buffer be flushed regardless since the text has been outputted to the screen?"*

No! `std::endl` implies flushing. The underlying buffer won't be flushing (*written on the screen*),
 until hitting a certain  *watermark* (buffer size).

If you want to have it flushed, call `cout.flush()` explicitely:

```
std::cout << "write to screen";
std::cout.flush();
```

The real key to the solution is, what the underlying **[`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf)** interface actually implements.
There could be various implementations:

1. Calling `flush()` every time the certain watermark of the underlying buffer is hit
2. Calling `flush()` every time (not very efficient)
3. Calling `flush()` as soon a `'\n'` had been printed
4. Calling `flush()` as guaranteed with `std::endl`

The internal buffer management shouldn't be your business of concern, unless you're trying to provide your own `std::basic_streambuf` implementation.

Comment: So, outputting to the screen does not free the memory used to store the text "write to screen"?

Comment: @Memnite  _"does not free the memory used to store the text "write to screen"?"_ There's no relation about _freed memory_ or memory management at all. Don't wrap your head around that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm just trying to understand this concept thoroughly before moving on to learn something new.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I think I have a better grasp of this now.